# GA4 new users are significantly higher than total users

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

we are facing a GA4 issue with our live site. The count of new users is higher than the count of total users. We have thoroughly examined various scenarios, but unfortunately, we have found no concrete solution. See the attected screenshot where you can find the new user count is higher then  totle user count.
[image]
[image]

Upon inspection of the explore tab, we have observed that certain "Effective user IDs" display over 100 new user counts, while the remaining existing users have only one user count per "Effective user ID". We are uncertain if this is the root cause of our main issue, which is the new user count higher than the total user count in GA4.

[image]

We have checked mutiple GA4 reports and other documentation. Also we have conducted thorough investigations on several cases in order to identify the root cause of the issue, but unfortunately, we have been unable to track down the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Users with high "first visit" counts will most certainly have an impact on your "New User" metric, since New Users are essentially all Users with a "first visit" event. Google uses Cookies and identifiers to determine which of those New Users are actually the same user, after the fact (after midnight i believe).

Basically, "Total Users" is a recalculated metric that corrects towards the actual number of "USERS" by definition of device/id/cookie/login data. It's probably in your interest to not create 317 fake "Users" for a single user that somehow generates multiple *first visit* events (dont ask me how)